# Build an Ethereum Wallet using React

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp, parity-wallet, react

Using React js i am trying to create a wallet

I want to implement few functionalities 
1) display balances of all the accounts
2) Display tokens by providing smart contract address

how can i implement this wallet functionality using reactjs??

Comment: Your question is too broad. Could you be more specific? What kind of problem you have?

Comment: I want to develop ethereum wallet using reactjs. In 1st i want to display balances, import wallets... normal wallet functionalities. I am new to react please help me out to start proceeding. My first task is to display balances

Comment: Did you tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/ethereumjs-wallet ?

Answer (score 3):

Basic JavaScript works perfectly fine in **[React](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(JavaScript_library)).** The most popular Ethereum JS library today seems to be the **[Web3 JavaScript API](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API).** Review their API to find your solutions and specifically **[balance requests.](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgetbalance)**

---

**[Ethers.js](https://docs.ethers.io/ethers.js/html/index.html)** is another fantastic library. Here is a snippet of code from our apps.

```
/* Import the ethers.js library. */
import ethers from 'ethers'

/* Initialize ethers classes. */
const _wallet    = ethers.Wallet
const _hdNode    = ethers.HDNode
const _providers = ethers.providers
const _utils     = ethers.utils

/* Connect to Ropsten (the test network). */
const TESTNET = false

/* Set the default provider. */
const PROVIDER = _providers.getDefaultProvider(TESTNET)

/* Retrieve the balance from a wallet address. */
const getBalanceByAddress = function (address) {
    return PROVIDER.getBalance(address)
        .then(balance => {
            /* Balance is a BigNumber (in wei). */
            let etherString = _utils.formatEther(balance)

            return etherString
        })
}
```

Importing / exporting wallets and building / sending transactions can be done from either library as well. Good luck!